# Keep together group of elements using CSS flex

Tags: css, flexbox

Let's take as an example this simple page with 5 boxes:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.general {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.item {
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="general">
  <div class="item"> item1 with some text to fill it up and make size</div>
  <div class="item"> item2 with some text to fill it up and make size</div>
  <div class="item"> item3 with some text to fill it up and make size</div>
  <div class="item"> item4 with some text to fill it up and make size</div>
  <div class="item"> item5 with some text to fill it up and make size</div>
</div>
```

I would like with some CSS to achieve a wrapping behavior where item1 and item2, and separately item4 and item5, stay together until they can.

Basically, if the user resize down the window horizontally, as soon they don't fit all in one line, I would like them to wrap like this:

```
item1 item2
item3
item4 item5
```

If the window gets shrunk even more, I expect the to wrap all in one column:

```
item1 
item2
item3
item4 
item5
```

Is there a way I can do it with some flex trick? I would like it to be more generic possible, so I can apply it to various scenarios with various items.

Comment: Are we allowed to modify the html if yes then its possible with flex

Comment: Just wrap those items you want to stick together in another element.

Comment: Flexbox won't automatically be able to do this with your current HTML. **You'll** need to determine when the wrap happens - most likely using media queries.

Comment: @HereticMonkey How can the five items always wrap into three rows (never only two rows) where item3 is in the middle row by itself? (I also assume that the width of item3 shouldn't double, but OP TommySimo should clarify.) I am unable to come up with a solution just by nesting containers and would like to learn from your solution.

Comment: @TimR Sounds like a new question :) Comments are meant to clarify or guide the OP, not to share solutions. If the OP clarifies whether the HTML can be modified by [edit]ing their question, I can share a solution. Or you could ask a related, more specific question.

Comment: @HereticMonkey A new question? :) No, I just pointed out what is being asked for (which includes an illustration of the desired result.) I don't see any mention of not being able to modify the HTML. Please help me understand when I should make that assumption. Thanks!

Comment: We like it when an asker is more involved with their question. Asking a question and then not checking the comments for a day is kind of bad form. In any case, I generally like to assume as little as possible so I don't waste time; I've invested a bunch of time in questions more complex than this, only to have the OP comment, "I can't change the HTML structure" *after* I post. So I comment, and wait. There are many, many, many other questions to look at :).

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can come up with to get one row to wrap into three rows with specific grouping is to use a media (or container) query.

This method requires declaring a width for the items and declaring `flex-direction: column` on the main container when the viewport is narrower than the combined total width of all items and gaps.

The HTML will have to be modified to group the desired items.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section, .group {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
}

.item {
  max-width: 250px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

@media (width < 1290px) {
  section {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="group">
    <div class="item">item1 with some text to fill it up and make size</div>
    <div class="item">item2 with some text to fill it up and make size</div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">item3 with some text to fill it up and make size</div>

  <div class="group">
    <div class="item">item4 with some text to fill it up and make size</div>
    <div class="item">item5 with some text to fill it up and make size</div>
  </div>
</section>
```