# In nested Flexbox, how to make a parent FlexBox to shrink and stay at the top and only wrap to next line if there is not enough room to show

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, bootstrap-5

In the example below, I have defined Flexbox instead another Flexbox.  For box 1, 2, and 3, I want them to stay on the right of box A (e.g. in desktop browser), and only shows them below box A if there is not enough space to show on the right of box A (e.g. in a smartphone browser).  What trick do I need to achieve it?

I am open for solutions using Bootstrap 4 or 5.

[image]

```
<html lang="en-us">
  <style>
    body, div {font-family: sans-serif; font-size:100px}
  </style>
  <body>
    <div style="display:flex; flex-flow:row wrap; justify-content:flex-start; align-items:flex-start; ">
      <div id="letter" style="background-color:red; min-width:150px; min-height:400px; margin:10px;">A</div>
      <div id="numbers"
           style="display:flex; flex-flow:row wrap;
                  justify-content:flex-start; align-items:flex-start;
                  background-color:yellow">
        <div style="background-color:lightblue; min-width:300px; min-height:200px; margin:10px">1</div>
        <div style="background-color:lightblue; min-width:300px; min-height:180px; margin:10px">2</div>
        <div style="background-color:lightblue; min-width:300px; min-height:150px; margin:10px">3</div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You've added tags for bootstrap 4 and bootstrap 5, but none of your code shows any bootstrap at all.  Are you using boostrap or not?  If so which version?  What you want can be done with bootstrap but your tags have made it unclear what you are using.

Comment: @ChrisBarr  It would be great if you can show me how to do it in Bootstrap, preferrably version 5.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If flex items are allowed to wrap, the items will wrap before their width is reduced.

The only way to control this behavior is to change the wrap declaration at a targeted width using a media query.

```css
@media (max-width: 490px) {
  .container {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}
```

I gave a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76919204/21849374) to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76869215/keep-together-group-of-elements-using-css-flex) a couple of days ago.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 100px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

@media (max-width: 490px) {
  .container {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}

#letter {
  background-color: red;
  min-width: 150px;
  min-height: 400px;
  margin: 10px;
}

#numbers {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#numbers div {
  background-color: lightblue;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
}

#numbers div:nth-child(1) {
  min-height: 200px;
}

#numbers div:nth-child(2) {
  min-height: 180px;
}

#numbers div:nth-child(3) {
  min-height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="letter">A</div>
  <div id="numbers">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

The [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) framework uses media queries for the various breakpoints, so this can be accomplished with Bootstrap.

I didn't have time to include a Bootstrap  solution yesterday and planned to edit my answer today. Even though you've already accepted my answer after Chris Barr posted an elaborate Bootstrap [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76935123/21849374), I'll include my suggested modification of his solution.

Bootstrap requires nesting container elements due to how margin, padding, and Flexbox properties are applied. That's why extra `div`s are needed just for the row and column classes. Using `gap-*` or `column-gap-*` classes on the same column element causes the columns to not fit in the row because the gap increases the column width.

I am assuming that the given `min-height` declarations are only to replace the actual content in the example and wouldn't be used in production.

Differences between my Bootstrap solution and Chris':

- `container-fluid` for 100% width
- added `row-gap-2` for vertical spacing when items are wrapped
- different column breakpoints for `letter` and `numbers`
- removed `col-12` because that's already the default for children of `row`

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row row-gap-2">
  
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
      <div id="letter" class="bg-danger" style="min-height:400px;">A</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9">
      <div id="numbers" class="row row-gap-2 bg-warning">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <div class="bg-info" style="min-height:200px;">1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <div class="bg-info" style="min-height:180px;">2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <div class="bg-info" style="min-height:150px;">3</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do it using only bootstrap classes.  I encourage you to read up on the bootstrap grid system to learn how this works: [Grid Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/layout/grid/) and [Column Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/layout/columns/)

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  
    <div class="col-3">
      <div id="letter" class="bg-danger" style="min-height:400px;">A</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-12 col-md-9">
      <div id="numbers" class="row bg-warning">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <div class="bg-info" style="min-height:200px;">1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <div class="bg-info" style="min-height:180px;">2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <div class="bg-info" style="min-height:150px;">3</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### Bootstrap Column Explanation

The quick version is that you have a `row` and the **only** elements that can be directly inside of that are columns, which have `col-*` classes. Do not style a row or a column in any way that changes its size!

Each row has 12 columns available to use inside it. So if you had two `col-6` elements, each one would take up 50% of the available space.

```html
<div class="row">  
  <div class="col-6">half</div>
  <div class="col-6">half</div>
</div>
```

You can break that up however you want as long as it adds up to 12.  3 `col-4`'s, a `col-6` and 2 `col-3`'s, or even 12 `col-1`'s.

If you go over 12, it will wrap to the next line.  So 3 `col-6`'s will show the first two on the first line, and then the 3rd one on the next line.

#### Column Breaks

You can define different column sizes at different screen sizes too! The screen sizes are defined by bootstrap and you [can see them all here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/layout/grid/#grid-options).  It's important to work from the smallest size and then go upwards, never work in the opposite direction.

If I had a column with `col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4` on it, that means at the smallest size it will take up all 12 columns, when the screen gets bigger it will change to only take up 6 columns, and then even bigger it will only take up 4 columns.

You can also nest rows inside of the column of another row.  It's not as complex as it might seem.  Just remember that a `row` takes up 100% of the width available to it.  The columns are percentages of that width, not a hard-set pixel value

Answer (score 0):

it's possible, all you have to do is to give the both A[div] and numbers[div] a `float:left;` then every thing will be just like you want it. but be sure divs have a display of block otherwise the float won't work.